# PInvoke ReadProcessMemory - Reading PEB with ReadProcessMemory: "Invalid handle"

Tags: c#, winapi, process, pinvoke

I am trying to read the value of `ImageBaseAddress` in the `PEB` of a process I have created using `Win32` API calls in C# with P/Invoke. However the call to `ReadProcessMemory` returns false, indicating it has failed. <strike>Inspecting with Visual Studio debugger I see the bytes array passed to the function is populated with zeroes. However a Win32Exception isn't raised, printing `Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message` gives `The operation completed successfully.`</strike>

Edit:
After addressing issues highlighted in the comments that I wasn't actually retrieving the latest Win32 error, I now see that the error I am getting is `Invalid handle`

Below is my code, and two screenshots to help illustrate my point.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ReadProcess
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public int dwProcessId;
            public int dwThreadId;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            uint cb;
            IntPtr lpReserved;
            IntPtr lpDesktop;
            IntPtr lpTitle;
            uint dwX;
            uint dwY;
            uint dwXSize;
            uint dwYSize;
            uint dwXCountChars;
            uint dwYCountChars;
            uint dwFillAttributes;
            uint dwFlags;
            ushort wShowWindow;
            ushort cbReserved;
            IntPtr lpReserved2;
            IntPtr hStdInput;
            IntPtr hStdOutput;
            IntPtr hStdErr;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr ExitStatus;
            public IntPtr PebAddress;
            public IntPtr AffinityMask;
            public IntPtr BasePriority;
            public IntPtr UniquePID;
            public IntPtr InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
        [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int NtQueryInformationProcess(IntPtr processHandle, int processInformationClass, IntPtr processInformation, uint processInformationLength, IntPtr returnLength);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hProcess);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool CreateProcess(IntPtr lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, IntPtr lpProcAttribs, IntPtr lpThreadAttribs, bool bInheritHandles, uint dwCreateFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, IntPtr lpCurrentDir, [In] ref STARTUPINFO lpStartinfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcInformation);


        public static IntPtr GetPEBAddress(IntPtr hProcess)
        {
            //Allocate memory for a new PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION structure
            IntPtr pbi = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION)));
            //Allocate memory for a long
            IntPtr outLong = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(long));
            IntPtr outPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

            int queryStatus = 0;

            //Store API call success in a boolean
            queryStatus = NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, 0, pbi, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION)), outLong);

            //Close handle and free allocated memory
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(outLong);

            //STATUS_SUCCESS = 0, so if API call was successful querySuccess should contain 0 ergo we reverse the check.
            if (queryStatus == 0)
                outPtr = Marshal.PtrToStructure<PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION>(pbi).PebAddress;

            //Free allocated space
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pbi);

            //Return pointer to PEB base address
            return outPtr;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            STARTUPINFO startInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
            PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

            CreateProcess((IntPtr)0, "notepad", (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0, false, 0x00000004, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0, ref startInfo, out procInfo);

            byte[] ImageBaseAddress = new byte[IntPtr.Size];
            IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead;
            IntPtr pPEB = GetPEBAddress(procInfo.hProcess);
            ReadProcessMemory(procInfo.hProcess, pPEB + 16, ImageBaseAddress, 8, out lpNumberOfBytesRead);
            string errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;

            Console.WriteLine("File handle: 0x{0:X16}", procInfo.hProcess);
            Console.WriteLine("PEB base address: 0x{0:X16}", pPEB);
            Console.WriteLine("Last Win32 Error: {0}", errorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the program compared with the output of `!peb` in a WinDBG session that is attached to the notepad process.
[image: WinDBG and console]

Here is a screenshot of Visual Studio debugger, the breakpoint is on the `Console.WriteLine` call, after `ReadProcessMemory` has been called. (edit: Win32 error is now outdated but this screenshot still highlights that I am correctly identifying the PEB base address).
[image: Visual Studio debugger]

Comment: You're calling `GetLastWin32Error` far too late.  It's telling you about the result of the most recent operation, which happened somewhere inside `Console.WriteLine`.  Call `GetLastWin32Error` *immediately* after `ReadProcessMemory`, save its result in a variable.  Then do your logging.

Comment: The only operation that is safe to do in between the `ReadProcessMemory` call and `GetLastWin32Error` call is saving the `ReadProcessMemory` return value into a variable.  You can't print it.  You shouldn't manipulate it.  Store return value and last-error value first and only after they are safely stored can you do things with them.

Comment: You are also not validating whether `CreateProcess()` was successful before then attempting to access the spawned process.

Comment: @BenVoigt  Thanks, after taking this into consideration I found that the real Win32 error I'm getting is "Invalid handle". Any ideas?

Comment: @redpanda2236: You're closing the handle inside `GetPEBAddress`, then continuing to use it.  That would definitely cause "invalid handle".

Comment: @BenVoigt Huge facepalm moment... If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it. Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

You have many glaring errors in your PInvoke code.

- **Your primary issue:** You cannot see the error code, as you are not checking `GetLastWin32Error` immediately after the call. It cannot wait as it gets overwritten quickly by other calls.
  Furthermore, `NtQueryInformationProcess` doesn't use `SetLastError` at all, it returns a `NTSTATUS`. [You can find the full `enum` list here.](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/NtStatus.html)
- Ideally you should force Unicode using `CreateProcessW` and `CharSet.Unicode`. Also use `SafeFileHandle` for the process and thread handles, and use `using` rather than `CloseHandle` to dispose them.
  **But in this case I recommend you just create the process using `Process.Create`.** Then you don't need to manage that handle, you just need to put the `Process` into a `using`.
- The call to `ReadProcessMemory` should use `IntPtr.Size` to match the buffer array.
- Do not attempt manual marshalling unless you know what you are doing. You have memory leaks all over, and none of it is necessary as you can just pass in `string` and `ref` parameters where necessary.
- Some `IntPtr` and `uint` types are wrong also.

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
{
    public int ExitStatus;
    public IntPtr PebAddress;
    public IntPtr AffinityMask;
    public int BasePriority;
    public IntPtr UniquePID;
    public IntPtr InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool ReadProcessMemory (
    IntPtr hProcess,
    IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
    [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
    int dwSize,
    out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

[DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = false)]
static extern NtStatus NtQueryInformationProcess(
    IntPtr processHandle,
    int processInformationClass,
    out PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION processInformation,
    int processInformationLength,
    out int returnLength);
```

```cs
public static IntPtr GetPEBAddress(SafeFileHandle hProcess)
{
    var result = NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, 0, out var pbi, Marshal.SizeOf<PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION>(), out var outLong);

    if(result != NtStatus.Success)
        throw new Exception(result.ToString());

    return pbi.PebAddress;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        using (var proc = Process.Start("notepad.exe"))
        {
            byte[] ImageBaseAddress = new byte[IntPtr.Size];
            IntPtr pPEB = GetPEBAddress(proc.Handle);
            if(!ReadProcessMemory(proc.Handle, pPEB + 16, ImageBaseAddress, IntPtr.Size, out var lpNumberOfBytesRead))
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            Console.WriteLine("PEB base address: 0x{0:X16}", pPEB);
            // use ImageBaseAddress here ??
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Last Win32 Error: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**I must say, this whole thing seems rather suspect,** as you appear to be trying to read the PEB block. But the PEB block can and does change between different versions of Windows. In particular, offset `16` [does not appear to line up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-peb#remarks) with anything either in x64 or x86.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. Even using Process.Start as you suggest I get "The handle is invalid" Win32 error.

Comment: Have given further updayte